# Excel VBA macro to create custom lists from a selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, vba

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me create a macro that will add a selection to excels custom list. Typically to do this I select a a series of rows in one column, then I got to file, options, advanced and scroll to the very bottom and click edit custom lists. When going through this with the macro creator turned on all I get is a very simple script that is related to the specific cells I have selected. I would like to tweak the code so that it is using whatever I have currently selected to add to the custom list. That way I am not always tied down to the J4-J9 Range. Below is the code I receive.

```
Sub Customlistadd()
'
' Customlistadd Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+I
'
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Range("J4:J8")
End Sub
```

Is it as simple as adding current selection in place of j4:j8? If so how do I do I write that exactly? Do I first need to declare a variable type to hold the current section? Almost all examples I've looked at that seem to be attempting to do something along the lines of what I am trying to do tend to use variables to hold the current selections range. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use the `Selection` object, which will always contain the currently selected cells (if more than 1 is selected). i.e.

```
Application.AddCustomList Selection
```

And make sure your custom list only contains letters, not numbers. e.g. A,B,C,D,E,F,G,... or A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,... are fine, but 1,2,3,4,5 isn't.

Comment: I have tried the following combinations, none of which have run successfully. Could you provide a little more clarification `Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Range("selection")` `Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Range(selection)` `Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Range selection"` `Application.AddCustomList ListArray:= selection` `Application.AddCustomList selection` None the combinations I have have tried run correctly. I know I must be screwing up the syntax but I just can't figure out where.

Comment: Just use the command as Rhys Gibson has posted. No `ListArray` or `Range`. Just use `Application.AddCustomList Selection`

Comment: Unfortunately that is how I have already tried to write the code but it fails to run. `Sub Customlistadd()
'
' Customlistadd Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+I
'
    Application.AddCustomList Selection
End Sub` That is the entirety of my code and I get stopped on the line with the Selection object. Any other ideas? I end up receiving a run time error 1004

Comment: Make sure your custom list only contains letters, not numbers. e.g. A,B,C,D,E,F,G,... is fine, but 1,2,3,4,5 isn't.

Comment: They are 20 digit strings of numbers that are formatted as text. Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: Possibly. can you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Public Sub CreateCustomList()
  Dim v As Variant
  Dim rng As Excel.Range

  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A3")

  'Transpose from 2 dim array to 1 dim array
  v = Application.Transpose(Selection)

  'Add the custom list
  Application.AddCustomList v

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with add , get and delete custom list.
 Tip: Blank cells treat as countable order,kindly don't use blank cells

```
Sub CoustomList()

    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim N As Long    
    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=Sheet1.Range("A2:A4")
    Arr = Sheet1.Range("A2:A4")
    N = Application.GetCustomListNum(Arr)
    Application.DeleteCustomList N

End Sub
```